# Can we add version control for individual objects in Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know we can add Version control for the whole bucket but can we add the version control separately for individual objects in a bucket.

Comment: No, it's a bucket level setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not possible to selectively apply versioning** to specific objects in Amazon S3.

However, you could **suspend versioning** when you do not require it, then **resume versioning** when you wish to keep new versions of objets.